# In MVC 3, While rendering already selected value in Dropdown no rendering selected index

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am using VB.NET with MVC 3 application. I am trying to render Dropdown of years. where as I am having database, which shows my object selected with specific year. I tried following code

```
Controller:
         Dim _years As New List(Of Service.Year)
                    _years = _Svc.GetYears()
                    Dim _yearList As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = From c In _years Select New SelectListItem() With {.Text = c.YearMember, .Value = c.YearMember, .Selected = True}
                    ViewData("Year") = _yearList

In View : 
  Select Year :   <%: Html.DropDownList("Year", TryCast(ViewData("Year"), SelectList))%>
```

This is showing last value as selected in dropdown. if I removes .Selected=True It just load Drop down with Years entries as it is in Year table in database. Suppose years list is from 1992 to 2013. and my object having year say 1995 then expected is, while render the data , dropdown should render with selection 1995.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the last item is being displayed as selected is because you're setting the Selected flag as true for every single item, and given that only one item can be selected, the last one to be rendered is the one marked as selected.

You would have to do something like

```
Dim _years As New List(Of Service.Year)
                    _years = _Svc.GetYears()
                    Dim _yearList As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = From c In _years Select New SelectListItem() With {.Text = c.YearMember, .Value = c.YearMember, .Selected = c.YearMember == AVariableHere}
                    ViewData("Year") = _yearList
```

my VB Syntax might be a little off, but the idea is that you only set Selected = true for the one item that meets the criteria that you want, by comparing the YearMember property of each item to a variable, or pass it to a method that determines whether that specific item should be marked as selected.